# Permission denied when moving file

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am trying to move file to another folder but it gives  Permission denied error. Here is the permission of that files.

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root www-data  394 Oct 11 14:40 namechange.xml*


-rwxrwxrwx   1 root www-data  395 Oct 11 14:40 namechange1.xml*


-rwxrwxrwx   1 root www-data  345 Oct 11 14:40 roomchange.xml*
```

and here id the code that I used to move files

```
 rename("resources/xml_checkin/namechange.xml", "resources/xml_checkout/test.xml")

;
```

Comment: What about destination folder ?

Comment: So you've `777'd` the files (euurgh) but you've said nothing about the ownership/permissions of the directories.

Comment: Also, what user is running PHP?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx+  2 root www-data 4096 Oct 11 14:40 xml_checkin/                                                                         
drwxrwxrwx+  2 root www-data 4096 Oct 11 13:51 xml_checkout/
 here id directories permission

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Please open your terminal
2. Login with ssh
3. locate to the destination file using cd /var/www/html
4. Give permission to the particular folder using command chmod -R 777 path/folder or command chmod -R 777 path/filename
5. First try to change the chmod to 775, if it doesn't work then use 777

then try to move your files and see the result.
If issue persists again, let me know.

Comment: 1: you should **never** need to 777 **anything** on a web server 2: the OP has stated the files and folder are already 777

Comment: that's why I asked to use 775 first.

Comment: *"if it doesn't work then use 777"* <- **nope** ... if it doesn't work, sort out the file/directory ownership and group permissions (if required); no directory should ever need anything more permissive than 770 on a web server.

Comment: sometimes it do not work due to ownership, so we can change them using ssh.